# Oracle 19c - Multiple If Conditions

Tags: oracle, trigger, oracle-19c, condition

```
create or replace TRIGGER trigger_name
...
...
BEGIN
IF SYS_CONTEXT (...) IN (...) THEN
IF SYS_CONTEXT (...) NOT IN (...) THEN
IF SYS_CONTEXT (...) NOT IN (...) THEN
INSERT INTO owner.table_name (...) VALUES
      (...);
       COMMIT;
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(...);
END IF;
END IF;
END IF;
END;
```

As I mentioned above, there is a trigger.
Trigger should run and insert in the table when it doesn't provide even 1 of the if condition containing 2 not ins. However, when 1 of these 2 not in conditions is met, the trigger does not work as I want. How can I provide this? If even 1 of the 2 conditions is not met, the trigger should run.

The following table describes the logic of the trigger.

- *1st condition is met* means that `SYS_CONTEXT (...) IN (...)`.
- *2nd condition is met* means that `SYS_CONTEXT (...) NOT IN (...)`.
- *3nd condition is met* means that `SYS_CONTEXT (...) NOT IN (...)`.

Table:

```
1st condition is met  | y | y | ...
2nd condition is met  | y | y | 
3rd condition is met  | y | y |
execute insert        | ? | ? |
```

Comment: your description is rather unclear. I started with a table that describes the behaviour of the trigger. Please complete this table.

Comment: @miracle173 I solved and will delete this question.